# Data quality Services Internal behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, data-quality-services

When creating a knowledge basis on DQS, we can only select SQL Server and Excel from the drop down.

I want to query oracle. 
To do that, I thought of creating a view on SQL Server that selects from a Oracle linked server but I'm worried about performance.

Lets say my table has 10k rows, I wouldn't mind the impact of running a query against the linked server that returns 10k rows as long as it is run only ONCE.

My question is: does DQS loads all the data it needs to perform the cleansing operation in one go or does it keep submitting queries to the data source (oracle in my example) during the cleansing process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll need to export your Oracle data into a format that can be imported into DQS.  It's a one-time data import for a cleansing project.  I've made a series of short (<5 min each) [screencasts](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL41EB59B228FECB9B&feature=plcp) on DQS - this might be helpful as you are getting started.

Also, do install [CU1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2679368) before you start using DQS as the update improves performance substantially.

Comment: thanks for the consideration, but that was not exactly what I was looking for. I dont actually need to import it from oracle, I can access it though a view but I want to know if DQS constantly queries the source or if it does in one go, loads all the data into a stating area and works with it on that area

Comment: OK to directly answer, no you can't import from Oracle. Also DQS imports the data 1 time

Answer (score 0):

Yes the view in SQL pointing to ORACLE over a linked server "fools" the DQS into thinking the local data is in SQL.  The data is accessed once and copied to the DQS database and processed there.

I would recommend installing 2012 SP1 instead of the CU as there is more stable/ tested updates there.  Once you install SP1 you will need to run

```
DQSInstaller.exe –upgrade
```

This file in a default install is located in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn
```